# Unsubscribing from Crunchyroll Premium guest pass emails

Tags: account-management, crunchyroll

As a member of Crunchyroll Premium, users are occasionally sent free guest passes for Crunchyroll premium. Despite repeatedly clicking "unsubscribe", Crunchyroll still sends these emails every few months. Even [unsubscribing from all Crunchyroll emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp6DB.png) has had no effect.

Is there any way to get Crunchyroll to stop sending emails about guest passes?

[image: Crunchyroll Premium guest pass email]

Comment: You probably need to talk directly to their support and/or report them to the [Federal Trade Commission](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0038-spam#report). They're supposed to honor unsubscribe requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is to create an email filter to archive any message from "@crunchyroll.com" with the subject line "Gift Your Crunchyroll Premium+ Guest Pass".

It won't stop the emails being sent, but it should keep them out of your inbox.

[image: Gmail filter for "Gift your Crunchyroll Premium+ Guest Pass"]